# Как спарсить эту ссылку?

Tags: python, парсер

Нужно спарсить ссылку на **страницу для каждой пары**  https://www.lamoda.ru/c/5972/shoes-muzhkedy/?sitelink=topmenuM&l=4&brands=1061,1163,4035,5816,2047,1107&is_sale=1&page=1
[image: вот здесь фото для детального рассмотрения]

много раз это делал, а тут не получается `

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    "accept": "*/*",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" ,
  
}
def get_page(url):
    req = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
    src =req.text
    #print(src) 

    with open("lamoda2.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(src) 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")

    cards = soup.find("div", class_="x-product-card__card").find("div", class_="x-product-card__link x-product-card__hit-area").find("a",class_=" x-product-card__pic x-product-card__pic-catalog").get("href")
    print(cards)
    

def main():
    get_page(url="https://www.lamoda.ru/c/5972/shoes-muzhkedy/?sitelink=topmenuM&l=4&brands=1061,1163,4035,5816,2047,1107&page=1")
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`

ошибка `

```
File "c:/Users/Константин/Downloads/dodit/tgparser.py", line 20, in get_page
    cards = soup.find("div", class_="x-product-card__card").find("div", class_="x-product-card__link x-product-card__hit-area").find("a",class_=" x-product-card__pic x-product-card__pic-catalog").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: cards = soup.find("div", class_="x-product-card__card").find("a").get("href")

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


all_categories = []
page = 1
while True:
    url = f"https://www.lamoda.ru/c/5972/shoes-muzhkedy/?sitelink=topmenuM&l=4&" \
          f"brands=1061,1163,4035,2047,1107&is_sale=1&sort=discount&page={page}"
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all('a', class_="x-product-card__link")
    if not cards:
        break
    for card in cards:
        card_text = card.find(class_="x-product-card-description__product-name").text.strip()
        card_href = "https://www.lamoda.ru/" + card.get('href')
        all_categories.append([card_text, card_href])
    page += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

В переменной cards, в последнем обращении .find в названии класса впереди лишний пробел.

Comment: это так и задумано :) class=" x-product-card__pic x-product-card__pic-catalog", равносильно такой записи class=" x-product-card__pic" class=" x-product-card__pic-catalog" в HTML

Comment: Ну я проверил код прежде чем писать ответ.

Comment: Ну и уберем мы лишний пробел, проблема не исчезнет. find("div", class_="x-product-card__link x-product-card__hit-area") = None во всем коде HTML нет тега div с классом "x-product-card__link".

Comment: Пожалуйста попробуйте найти: a.x-product-card__pic.x-product-card__pic-catalog и ищите не div, а тег "a". Мне кажется, что вы не воспроизвели код из вопроса.

Comment: Даже пытатся не буду не вижу смысла.